# Unable to write message with ObjectInputStream and also the server does not connect

Tags: java, objectinputstream

This are the classes. The first class is used in order to create two methods 
sendMessage which are suppossed to write the messages.
       package poo_tema4;

```
   import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
   import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
   import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
   import java.io.ObjectStreamException;
   import java.io.Serializable;
   import java.net.Socket;
   import java.util.Date;

/**
 *
 * @author Stefan
 */
public class ClientPeer implements Serializable {


    private Socket socket;
    private String senderName;


//    private static Socket socket = null;
//    private static OutputStream outputStream = null;
//    private static InputStream inputStream = null;

    public ClientPeer(String senderName, Socket socket) {

    this.socket = socket;
    this.senderName = senderName;

    }



    public void sendMessage(String message) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException,ObjectStreamException {

        Message newMessage = new Message(message,"Hey how are you");


        try {

                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                out.writeObject(newMessage);
                out.flush();
                out.close();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to write this message");
        }

        try {

                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                Message msg;
                msg = (Message)ois.readObject();
                System.out.println(msg.getMessage());
                ois.close();


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to read this message" + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(ObjectStreamException e)
        {
          System.out.println("Unable to read this  message" + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(IOException e)

        {
          System.out.println("Unable to read this  message" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void sendMessage(String message, String receiver) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException,ObjectStreamException {

        PrivateMessage newPrivateMessage = new PrivateMessage(message, "Fine!", receiver);

        try {

            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 
            out.writeObject(newPrivateMessage);
            out.flush();
            out.close();



        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to write this private message");
        }

        try {

                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                PrivateMessage prvMsg = (PrivateMessage) ois.readObject();
                System.out.println(prvMsg.getPrivateMessage());
                ois.close();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to read this private message" + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(ObjectStreamException e)
        {
          System.out.println("Unable to read this private message" + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(IOException e)

        {
          System.out.println("Unable to read this private message" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}






/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package poo_tema4;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Stefan
 */
public class TextClient {

    private static Socket socket = null;
    private static OutputStream outputStream = null;
    private static InputStream inputStream = null;
    private static String sender = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {


            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",9000);

            if(socket.isConnected()==true){
            System.out.println("The socket is connected");

            }
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            outputStream.write("GET /java.txt\n".getBytes());
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please insert the sender name:");

            if(socket.isConnected()==true){
            while(sc.hasNextLine())
            {
             sender = sc.nextLine();
             ClientPeer client = new ClientPeer(sender, socket);
             client.sendMessage(sender);
             client.sendMessage(sender+"John");

            }}



        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Communication problem" + e.getMessage());

        }




    }

}


/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package poo_tema4;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 *
 * @author Stefan
 */
public class Message implements Serializable {

    private String senderName;
    private String content;

    public Message(String senderName, String content) {
        this.senderName = senderName;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getMessage() {

        String returnedMessage = senderName + ": " + content;
        return returnedMessage;

    }

}



/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package poo_tema4;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 *
 * @author Stefan
 */
public class PrivateMessage implements Serializable {


  private String senderName; 
  private String content;
  private String receiverName;

    public PrivateMessage(String senderName, String content, String receiverName) {
        this.senderName = senderName;
        this.content = content;
        this.receiverName = receiverName;
    }


     public String getPrivateMessage() {

        String returnedMessage = "(priv)"+senderName + ": " + content;
        return returnedMessage;

    }

    public String getReceiverName() {
        return receiverName;
    }





}
```

The error that i get is Communication problemConnection refused: connect.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is because there is no server listening on localhost:9000

More specifically, this line:

```
socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",9000);
```

Attempts to open a network connection to `127.0.0.1` on port `9000`.  When there is nothing listening on that socket to accept connections you will get an IOException with the message "Connection refused".

I would recommend that in future instead of handling errors like this:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Communication problem" + e.getMessage());
}
```

You output the stack trace as well as that will give you the line number the original exception was thrown at:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Communication problem");
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. But can you help me to know how to open a network connection on that port?

Comment: If i change for example the socket port  to one with 80 (HTTP) from what i understand this will appear The socket is connected
Please insert the sender name:
asdasd
asdasd: Hey how are you
Unable to read this  messageSocket is closed
Unable to write this message
Unable to read this  messageSocket is closed

Comment: Your logic for opening a network connection is (mostly) correct, but you need to have a server accepting connections on that port running.  It might help if you explain overall what it is you're trying to do

Comment: What i am trying to do is the following .  I want to send messages ( Both Message or Private Message) via a socket and i want to serialize them in the sendMessage methods using the current socket.

Comment: Also in the TextClient which is my main class i want to type the SenderName for example the program should work like the following

Comment: John: "he says something here "

Comment: This message should be serialized and read... from the socket

Comment: But the only thing that bothers me is the OutputStreamInput

Comment: For example for this code if i use another socket such as ("arh.pub.ro",80) The first object will be written and after that the socket will be closed.. What i want is the first message to be written and to be read also and if i type another one the same thing.

Comment: ah.pub.ro is a PUBLIC facing web server, it sounds like you're trying to create a chat system?